# Getting error when printing to Local Printer

Tags: winforms, printing

My users want to be able to print a report I've designed in VS 2010, directly, rather than doing through the process of previewing the report.  I've designed the report in VS 2010, using the report designer there, which has created a .rdlc file.  I'm using the following MSDN walkthrough as an example, for my code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091(v=VS.80).aspx

In my case, instead of data being in an XML file, I'm retrieving data from a SQL Server database, and I've got a .xsd file, etc.  Plus I'm passing parameters to the report.  It appears to be OK with my assigning the passed dataset and ReportParameters to the report.  Here's a segment of the code, the last line is the line where the error occurs:

`string deviceInfo =

    "<DeviceInfo>" +

    " <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" +

    " <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +

    " <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +

    " <MarginTop>0.4in</MarginTop>" +

    " <MarginLeft>0.5in</MarginLeft>" +

    " <MarginRight>0.5in</MarginRight>" +

    " <MarginBottom>0.4in</MarginBottom>" +

    "</DeviceInfo>";

Warning[] warnings;

m_streams = new List<Stream>();

report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);`

And here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred during local report processing.
  Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
       at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateStreamCallback createStream, Warning[]& warnings)
       at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, CreateStreamCallback createStream, Warning[]& warnings)
       at SimpleWinForms.PrintRfsDirectly.Export(LocalReport report) in C:\Users\Rodf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SimpleWinForms\SimpleWinForms\PrintRfsDirectly.cs:line 62
       at SimpleWinForms.PrintRfsDirectly..ctor(spRequestForServicesReport2DataTable RfsTable, ReportParameter AmciName, ReportParameter ClientNumberParameter, ReportParameter CaseNumberParameter, ReportParameter ClientNameParameter, String RdlcFileName) in C:\Users\Rodf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SimpleWinForms\SimpleWinForms\PrintRfsDirectly.cs:line 35
       at SimpleWinForms.ShowReport.ShowReport_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Rodf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SimpleWinForms\SimpleWinForms\ShowReport.cs:line 54
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
       at SimpleWinForms.Form1.btnPrintRFS_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Rodf\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SimpleWinForms\SimpleWinForms\Form1.cs:line 55
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at SimpleWinForms.Program.Main() in c:\users\rodf\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SimpleWinForms\SimpleWinForms\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException
       Message=An error has occurred during report processing.
       Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
       ExceptionLevelHelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsProcessingAborted&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=1.0
       SkipTopLevelMessage=false
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.AbortHelper.ThrowAbortException(String reportUniqueName)
            at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.CheckAndThrowIfAborted()
            at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RetrievalManager.FetchData(Boolean mergeTran)
            at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RetrievalManager.PrefetchData(ReportInstance reportInstance, ParameterInfoCollection parameters, Boolean mergeTran)
            at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.Merge.FetchData(ReportInstance reportInstance, Boolean mergeTransaction)
            at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.ProcessOdpReport(Report report, OnDemandMetadata odpMetadataFromSnapshot, ProcessingContext pc, Boolean snapshotProcessing, Boolean reprocessSnapshot, Boolean processUserSortFilterEvent, Boolean processWithCachedData, ErrorContext errorContext, DateTime executionTime, IChunkFactory cacheDataChunkFactory, StoreServerParameters storeServerParameters, GlobalIDOwnerCollection globalIDOwnerCollection, SortFilterEventInfoMap oldUserSortInformation, EventInformation newUserSortInformation, String oldUserSortEventSourceUniqueName, ExecutionLogContext executionLogContext, OnDemandProcessingContext& odpContext)
            at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.RenderReport(IRenderingExtension newRenderer, DateTime executionTimeStamp, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, IChunkFactory cacheDataChunkFactory, IChunkFactory yukonCompiledDefinition, Boolean& dataCached)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CreateSnapshotAndRender(CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, ReportProcessing repProc, IRenderingExtension renderer, ProcessingContext pc, RenderingContext rc, SubreportCallbackHandler subreportHandler, ParameterInfoCollection parameters, DatasourceCredentialsCollection credentials)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Render(CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, ParameterInfoCollection reportParameters, IEnumerable dataSources, DatasourceCredentialsCollection credentials, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, ReportRuntimeSetup runtimeSetup)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings)
       InnerException: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException
            Message=RfsDataSet
            Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
            ExceptionLevelHelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsErrorCreatingDataReader&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=1.0
            SkipTopLevelMessage=false
            StackTrace:
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeDataSet.RunDataSetQuery()
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.TablixProcessing.RuntimeOnDemandDataSet.Process()
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeDataSet.ProcessConcurrent(Object threadSet)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: Your exception dump got truncated just as it got interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all that VS 2010 gave me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this error as well and eventually tracked it down to a permission issue on creating the file stream within the CreateStream callback when running the render method.  When creating the file stream it threw an access exception.  Simply replaced the static filename with a unique temp name to resolve the issue:

```
    // Routine to provide to the report renderer, in order to save an image for each page of the report.
    private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
      string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {            
        Stream stream = new FileStream(Path.GetTempFileName(), FileMode.Create);            
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }
```